# How to use unboundedPreceding, unboundedFollowing and currentRow in rowsBetween in PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark, group-by

I am a little confused about the method [`pyspark.sql.Window.rowsBetween`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Window.rowsBetween.html) that accepts `Window.unboundedPreceding`, `Window.unboundedFollowing`, and `Window.currentRow` objects as `start` and `end` arguments. Could you please explain how the function works and how to use `Window` objects correctly, with some examples? Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Basically rows between/range between as name suggests helps with limiting the number of rows considered inside a window.

Lets take a simple example

Starting with data

```
dfw=spark.createDataFrame([("abc",1,100),("abc",2,200),("abc",3,300),("abc",4,200),("abc",5,100)],"name string,id int,price int")

#output
+----+---+-----+
|name| id|price|
+----+---+-----+
| abc|  1|  100|
| abc|  2|  200|
| abc|  3|  300|
| abc|  4|  200|
| abc|  5|  100|
+----+---+-----+
```

Now over this data lets try to find of running max i.e max for each row

```
dfw.withColumn("rm",F.max("price").over(Window.partitionBy("name").orderBy("id"))).show()

#output
+----+---+-----+---+
|name| id|price| rm|
+----+---+-----+---+
| abc|  1|  100|100|
| abc|  2|  200|200|
| abc|  3|  300|300|
| abc|  4|  200|300|
| abc|  5|  100|300|
+----+---+-----+---+
```

So as expected it looked at each price from top to bottom one by one and populated the max value it got this behavior is known as start= Window.unboundedPreceding to end=Window.currentRow

Now changing rows between values to start= Window.unboundedPreceding to end=Window.unbounded Following we will get as below

```
dfw.withColumn("rm",F.max("price").over(Window.partitionBy("name").orderBy("id").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding,Window.unboundedFollowing))).show()

#output
+----+---+-----+---+
|name| id|price| rm|
+----+---+-----+---+
| abc|  1|  100|300|
| abc|  2|  200|300|
| abc|  3|  300|300|
| abc|  4|  200|300|
| abc|  5|  100|300|
+----+---+-----+---+
```

Now as you can see in same window its looking downwards in all values for a max instead of limiting it to current row

Now third will be start=Window.currentRow and end =Window.unboundedFollowing

```
dfw.withColumn("rm",F.max("price").over(Window.partitionBy("name").orderBy("id").rowsBetween(Window.currentRow,Window.unboundedFollowing))).show()

#output
+----+---+-----+---+
|name| id|price| rm|
+----+---+-----+---+
| abc|  1|  100|300|
| abc|  2|  200|300|
| abc|  3|  300|300|
| abc|  4|  200|200|
| abc|  5|  100|100|
+----+---+-----+---+
```

Now its looking down only for a max starting its row from the current one.

Also its not limited to just these 3 to use as is you can even start=Window.currentRow-1 and end =Window.currentRow+1 so instead of looking for all values above or below it will only look 1 rows above and 1 rows below

like this

```
dfw.withColumn("rm",F.max("price").over(Window.partitionBy("name").orderBy("id").rowsBetween(Window.currentRow-1,Window.currentRow+1))).show()
# output
+----+---+-----+---+
|name| id|price| rm|
+----+---+-----+---+
| abc|  1|  100|200|
| abc|  2|  200|300|
| abc|  3|  300|300|
| abc|  4|  200|300|
| abc|  5|  100|200|
+----+---+-----+---+
```

So you can imagine it a window inside the window which works around the current row its processing

Comment: Great answer here and I know this is an old question but just to add that you don't need to specify window.currentRow within rowsBetween, as the values in here are automatically referenced from the current row. So instead rowsBetween(-1, 1) would do the same.